# Should I use RNAseZAP on my bench and pipettes before RNA extraction?

Tags: lab-techniques, rna, rna-sequencing, protocol

Should I spray RNAseZAP on my bench and pipettes before working with RNA? I am regularly using RNase at my bench and would like to work with RNA as well. Could traces of RNase on my equipment degrade my RNA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common practice in my lab is to work in a laminar flow cabinet and clean it with alcohol, then spray it with the RNAseZAP. I've always heard from my professors that, while DNAses are more uncommon, "RNAses are everywhere". So, zap it early, zap it all.

Comment: Do you know if it is safe to use RNAseZAP outside the hood? Can it harm us if we inhale the vapours?

Comment: @charlesdarwin I don't know the composition of RNAseZAP, but I don't think it can create harmful vapours. I suggested the hood because it prevents recontamination during the experiment, not for RNAseZAP safety problems (see "RNAses are everywhere")